# What request/response event classes are used with a Lambda triggered by Application Load Balancer

Tags: java, aws-lambda, aws-application-load-balancer

We are fronting Lambdas with an Application Load Balancer versus an API Gateway, but I can't find authoritative reference on the classes to use within the RequestHandler.  It appears it's the same as APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent or should it be APIGatewayV2ProxyRequestEvent?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ApplicationLoadBalancerRequestEvent / ApplicationLoadBalancerResponseEvent` classes. You should reference `com.amazonaws:aws-lambda-java-events` in your maven/gradle project file.